# CloudWatch Logs agent can't assume role to send logs to different account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have 2 AWS accounts.

- **Account A:** EC2 instances with awslogs client from amazon
- **Account B:** Centralized logging account

I want to send logs from the EC2 instance with awslogs client (**in account A**) from one account to CloudWatch Logs in an another account (**account B**).

It works fine by creating an IAM user in Account B and setting up the AWS credential key in `awscli.conf`, but I do not want keys to be hardcoded, so I'm trying to assume role as follows:

IAM Role in Account B (the CloudWatch account), I created a role name `CloudWatchCrossRole`:

Inline policy (allow this role to write logs to CloudWatch Logs):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "logs:*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Trust policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_A:role/CLoudWatchInstanceProfile"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

In Account A, I start an EC2 instance with the profile `CLoudWatchInstanceProfile` that looks as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_B:role/CloudWatchCrossRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

No joy, the logs are pushed to ACCOUNT_A instead of ACCOUNT_B. Can anyone give me hint whether AssumeRole on CloudWatch Logs is possible or if it is mandatory to create an IAM user and hardcode the credentials in `awscli.conf`?

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with this approach.

First, nothing is calling `AssumeRole` on the role in Account B. The CloudWatch Logs agent is expecting credentials, not a role.

Second, the Instance Profile in Account A cannot assign permissions to Account B.

Nor could I find any documentation to show how to insert credentials in the `awscli.conf` file you mentioned (can you show a sample)?

A couple of options:

- Create a User in Account B and provide the resulting Access/Secret key to the CloudWatch Logs agent (as you seem to have done, but don't like), or
- Have a process run on the instance that calls `AssumeRole` against the role in Account B, then provide those credentials to the CloudWatch Logs agent

If you are subscribed to AWS Support, open a support case to request guidance.

Comment: HI John, thanks for your answer, for the awscli.conf, here is the link: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html#running-ec2-step-2
Regarding cloudwatch, i just dont understand how other company does when they have multiple accounts and they want to aggregate all logs into a  secure log account, i thought it was a best practise. Why aws is making it so complicated

Comment: Found this, but I'm not sure it's what you want: [Amazon CloudWatch Logs - Cross Account Subscriptions](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/08/amazon-cloudwatch-logs-cross-account-subscriptions/)

Comment: Thanks again john,I knew this one but adding kinesis in between looked a bit overkill, i will try this project https://github.com/ryotarai/fluent-plugin-cloudwatch-logs and see.