# How to view AWS organisation's CloudTrail logs in the security account's CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudtrail, aws-organizations

The AWS CloudTrail logs are being stored into an S3 bucket in the Logs Account. The trail that generates these logs is in the Management Account. I would like the CloudTrail logs to be visible in CloudWatch in my Security Account.

I am (mostly) using the console, and I have set up various EventBridge permissions and Roles and so forth, detailed below. However, whenever I try to enable CloudWatch logs in the trail I get the error `An internal error occurred. Refresh the page, and retry.`

How do I make the CloudTrail logs visible in a log group in CloudWatch in my Security account?

---

Account and organisation structure is relatively simple - four accounts, with no SCP applied:

- Management Account
- Infrastructure Account
- Security Account
- Logs Account

The CloudTrail trail in the management account is storing the logs in the Logs Account bucket, this is enabled via a bucket policy (this is the template, placeholder values replaced by correct bucket name, management account id, organisation id, trail name, region):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailAclCheck20150319",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                    "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailWrite20150319",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                    "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET/AWSLogs/MANAGEMENT_ACCOUNT_ID/*/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control",
                    "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudtrail:REGION:MANAGEMENT_ACCOUNT_ID:trail/TRAIL_NAME"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailWrite20150319",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                    "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET/AWSLogs/ORGANISATION_ID/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control",
                    "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudtrail:REGION:MANAGEMENT_ACCOUNT_ID:trail/TRAIL_NAME"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The Security Account EventBridge `default` bus has the following resource permissions policy on it (this is the template, placeholder values replaced by security account id, organisation id, region):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Sid": "allow_all_accounts_from_organization_to_put_events",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": "*",
    "Action": "events:PutEvents",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:events:REGION:SECURITY_ACCOUNT_ID:event-bus/default",
    "Condition": {
      "StringEquals": {
        "aws:PrincipalOrgID": "ORGANISATION_ID"
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

The security account also has a CloudWatch log group with name "cloudtrail-logs".

In the Management Account, there is the TRAIL_NAME CloudTrail trail and I have created the CloudTrailForCloudWatchLogs-TRAIL_NAME role with the following permissions policy attached:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailCreateLogStream1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:REGION:SECURITY_ACCOUNT_ID:log-group:LOG_GROUP:log-stream:MANAGEMENT_ACCOUNT_ID_CloudTrail_REGION*",
                "arn:aws:logs:REGION:SECURITY_ACCOUNT_ID:log-group:LOG_GROUP:log-stream:ORGANISATION_ID*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailPutLogEvents2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:REGION:SECURITY_ACCOUNT_ID:log-group:LOG_GROUP:log-stream:MANAGEMENT_ACCOUNT_ID_CloudTrail_REGION*",
                "arn:aws:logs:REGION:SECURITY_ACCOUNT_ID:log-group:LOG_GROUP:log-stream:ORGANISATION_ID*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In order to try and enable CloudTrail into CloudWatch I do the following:

1. In the management account, go to CloudTrail, click on the TRAIL_NAME trail and then click on "Edit" by the CloudWatch Logs (this currently says "CloudWatch logs is not configured for this trail").
2. In the resulting edit screen:

- Check "CloudWatch logs enabled"
- Specify an existing log group: cloudtrail-logs
- Specify an existing IAM role: CloudTrailForCloudWatchLogs-TRAIL_NAME

3. At the bottom of this edit form there is a "Policy document" dropdown, expanding that shows the following policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailCreateLogStream2014110",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "logs:CreateLogStream"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:logs:REGION:MANAGEMENT_ACCOUNT_ID:log-group:LOG_GROUP:log-stream:MANAGEMENT_ACCOUNT_ID_CloudTrail_REGION*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailPutLogEvents20141101",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:logs:REGION:MANAGEMENT_ACCOUNT_ID:log-group:LOG_GROUP:log-stream:MANAGEMENT_ACCOUNT_ID_CloudTrail_REGION*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

4. Clicking the "Save Changes" button at the bottom of the Edit form generates the error message `An internal error occurred. Refresh the page, and retry.`. If I go to IAM I will also find a new policy matching exactly the one in step (3) just above has been created and attached to the CloudTrailForCloudWatchLogs-TRAIL_NAME role.

Specific resources that have helped me this far (these links will probably eventually go stale so I've provided detail above):

- Creating the trail and getting that working:

  - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/creating-trail-organization.html
  - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/create-s3-bucket-policy-for-cloudtrail.html
- Setting up the EventBridge, Management Account role:

  - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-required-policy-for-cloudwatch-logs.html
  - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/monitor-cloudtrail-log-files-with-cloudwatch-logs.html
  - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatchEvents-CrossAccountEventDelivery.html#ReceivingEventsFromAnotherAccount (note that these instructions are slightly out of date because they refer to CloudWatch event bus and this is now handled by EventBridge)
- And this StackOverflow question is close to this one, but not quite: it is about collecting CloudWatch logs from multiple accounts into one account: [Cloudtrail to Cloudwatch to other account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43279577/cloudtrail-to-cloudwatch-to-other-account)

**What about doing it via the CLI / update 2021-12-21**

Having already configured the EventBus in the SecurityAccount to accept events as described above, I then used the instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/send-cloudtrail-events-to-cloudwatch-logs.html#send-cloudtrail-events-to-cloudwatch-logs-cli). This also doesn't work, but fails with a more informative error message: `An error occurred (InvalidCloudWatchLogsLogGroupArnException) when calling the UpdateTrail operation: You must specify a log group that is owned by this account.`.

This suggests that it isn't possible for CloudWatch in Account B to monitor the logs written by CloudTrail in account A, at least not directly.

I am now investigating whether or not I can share the CloudTrail logs from the Management Account into the Security Account and so create the CloudWatch monitoring that way (starting [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-sharing-logs.html)).

---

In more detail, what I have done:

```
aws iam create-role --role-name ROLE_NAME --assume-role-policy-document file://path/to/cloudtrail_assume_role.json
aws iam put-role-policy --role-name ROLE_NAME --policy-name cloudtrail-for-cloudwatch-policy --policy-document file://path/to/role-policy-document.json
aws cloudtrail update-trail --name TRAIL_NAME --cloud-watch-logs-log-group-arn LOG_GROUP_ARN --cloud-watch-logs-role-arn ROLE_ARN
```

Where `cloudtrail_assume_role.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

And `role-policy-document.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailCreateLogStream1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogStream"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:REGION:SECURITY_ACCOUNT_ID:log-group:LOG_GROUP:log-stream:MANAGEMENT_ACCOUNT_ID_CloudTrail_REGION*",
                "arn:aws:logs:REGION:SECURITY_ACCOUNT_ID:log-group:LOG_GROUP:log-stream:ORGANISATION_ID_*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailPutLogEvents2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:REGION:SECURITY_ACCOUNT_ID:log-group:LOG_GROUP:log-stream:MANAGEMENT_ACCOUNT_ID_CloudTrail_REGION*",
                "arn:aws:logs:REGION:SECURITY_ACCOUNT_ID:log-group:LOG_GROUP:log-stream:ORGANISATION_ID_*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```